# indexing button in vb.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, button

my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn1.Click, btn2.Click, btn3.Click
    Dim objBtn() As Object = {btn1, btn2, btn3}
    Dim btn As Button
    With objBtn
        btn = CType(objBtn(x), Button)
        If btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard Then
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.OrangeRed
        Else
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

What must i do for the program to control the value of x automatically? that is, suppose i click on btn1, value of x must become 0; if i click on btn2, value of x must become 1 and so on. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you even putting the buttons in an array? And if you are already doing so, why declare it as `Object` instead of using `List(Of Button)` to make iteration easy?

Comment: Why not rather make use of the sender object, which would be the button in question.

Comment: Deleted the answer as oded was right, it is just a comment, added a rather jovial stab at getting x.

Comment: my idea is: i have 3 buttons and when i click on any of them, its FlatStyle should change. I can code each button seperately to perform this action but instead, i want only 1 procedure to do the task. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Whats being said is that sender is the button that sent the event.  you can simply do btn = CType(sender, Button)

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want. :D

`x = objBtn.IndexOf(sender)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to (badly) implement a `NumericUpDown` control.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/729xt55s.aspx

Jus drag&drop it into your Form, maybe set its properties, and it will be ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to set the state of one button differently from the others in the set.

Here's code to help you to do that.

```
Private Sub btn1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles _
btn1.Click, btn2.Click, btn3.Click
    Dim buttons() As Button = {btn1, btn2, btn3}

    For Each btn in buttons
        If btn Is sender Then
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard
        Else
            btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat
            btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.OrangeRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```